# Error calling Azure Forms Recognizer from within an Azure Blob Trigger Function

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I get an error (BadRequest) when calling the Azure Forms Recognizer .NET SDK from within an Azure Function (Blob Trigger)

I'm basically using the example code in the C# quickstart from the documentation. I have trained the model and can successfully call Form Recognizer from a .NET Core command line app, and also using cURL. I now want to trigger the same flow but when a PDF is uploaded to an Azure Storage Blob. Using the same modelId, subscription and endpoint in the Function I get a BadRequest error when calling AnalyzeWithCustomModelAsync(). I've tried many variations on the myBlob Stream, creating a FileStream, MemoryStream, creating a new Stream using the uri passed into the Function and more.

```
[FunctionName("ImportInvoice")]
        public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task RunAsync([BlobTrigger("originals/{name}", Connection = "invoiceConn")]Stream myBlob, string name, Uri uri, string blobTrigger, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"ImportInvoice Function triggered by new invoice: {name} size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
            log.LogInformation($"Invoice Uri: {uri.AbsoluteUri}");
            log.LogInformation($"System.IO.Stream.CanRead is: {myBlob.CanRead}");

            try
            {
                IFormRecognizerClient formClient = new FormRecognizerClient(new ApiKeyServiceClientCredentials(subscriptionKey))
                {
                    Endpoint = formRecognizerEndpoint
                };

                using (Stream invoiceStream = myBlob)
                {
                    log.LogInformation($"About to analyse with custom model {modelId}");

                    // Fails here with BadRequest
                    AnalyzeResult result = await formClient.AnalyzeWithCustomModelAsync(modelId, myBlob, contentType: "application/pdf");

                    log.LogInformation("Invoice analysed");

                    foreach (var page in result.Pages)
                    {
                        foreach (var kv in page.KeyValuePairs)
                        {
                            if (kv.Key.Count > 0 && kv.Value.Count > 0)
                                log.LogInformation(kv.Key[0].Text + ": " + kv.Value[0].Text);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (ErrorResponseException e)
            {
                log.LogInformation("Analyze PDF form : " + e.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.LogInformation("Analyze PDF form : " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

I'm passing in the modelId, the Stream passed to the function (myBlob) and the correct content type (application/pdf). I expect the formClient.AnalyzeWithCustomModelAsync(modelId, myBlob, contentType: "application/pdf") call to succeed and to see the key and values (the same code works outside a function) but I get the following:

```
Executing 'ImportInvoice' (Reason='New blob detected: originals/NewCareInvoice5.pdf', Id=63f26c79-f269-4ea8-b6e8-8b4f6d6eb6e2)
ImportInvoice Function triggered by new invoice: NewCareInvoice5.pdf size: 134507 Bytes
Invoice Uri: https://myinvoices.blob.core.windows.net/originals/NewCareInvoice5.pdf
System.IO.Stream.CanRead is: True
About to analyse with custom model <correct model id shown here>
Analyze PDF form : Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'
```

I'm assuming the issue is the Stream but I've gone round in circles trying to reference it or create or copy a new stream and seem to be missing something. I can't get any more details on the error (e.g. from InnerException).

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has updated the form recognition to V2.0 preview,  with updated API and tutorials, please try the new version. 
http://aka.ms/formrecognizer

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug on the Form Recognizer SDK.
I hope it's fixed soon.

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/40938